# React Private Routing

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication

I created a react application and i need to use private routing in it. The following is the method that I used to do it. But it pops up error when importing the Redirect component. Why is that?

Here is the app.js file.

```
import React from "react";
import {Route, Router} from "react-router-dom";
import Login from "./pages/login/index";
import Register from "./pages/Register/index";
import Dashboard from "./pages/Dashboard/index";
import {AuthContextProvider, useAuthState} from "./firebase";

const AuthenticatedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...props }) => {
    const { isAuthenticated } = useAuthState();
    return (
        <Route
            {...props}
            render={routeProps =>
                isAuthenticated ? <Component {...routeProps} /> : <Redirect to="/login" />
            }
        />
    );
};

const UnauthenticatedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...props }) => {
    const { isAuthenticated } = useAuthState();
    return (
        <Route
            {...props}
            render={routeProps =>
                !isAuthenticated ? <Component {...routeProps} /> : <Redirect to="/" />
            }
        />
    );
};

function App() {
    return (
        <AuthContextProvider>
            <Router>
                <AuthenticatedRoute exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
                <UnauthenticatedRoute path="/register" component={Register} />
                <UnauthenticatedRoute path="/login" component={Login} />
            </Router>
        </AuthContextProvider>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Here is the index.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import {BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <React.StrictMode>
            <App />
        </React.StrictMode>
    </BrowserRouter>

);

reportWebVitals();
```

Here is the firebase.js file

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth,onAuthStateChanged} from "firebase/auth";
import {createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState} from "react";

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: ""
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const authenticate = getAuth(app);

export const AuthContext = createContext()

export const AuthContextProvider = props => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState();
    const [error, setError] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(authenticate,setUser, setError)
        return () => unsubscribe();
    },[]);
    return <AuthContext.Provider value={{user,error}} {...props}/>
}

export const useAuthState = () => {
    const auth = useContext(AuthContext);
    return{
        ...auth, isAuthenticated: auth.user != null
    }
};
```

I tried changing the versions of react-router-dom but it didn't work.I expect the help to figure out the issue and the way to solve it